# becubed oletool missing function call servertime.refresh

Tags: vb6

I am trying to compile code using the becubed oletools as a depencency in VB6. I am unable to reference a function called servertime.refresh. This call is in the ServerTimeDisplay.ctl control file. This is a so called legacy program I am working. The code was written about 20 years ago. I am trying to duplicate the compilation environment that created the original project.

I have added the controls file to my project but the function call to servertime.refresh causes a compilation error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgb8G.png)

Comment: Have you set a reference to this tool from Project | References?  Also, it would be useful to add the error message to your question.

Comment: It looks like the variable in question is `ServerTime` - how and where is this defined?

Comment: You should paste that screenshot directly into the question text so the image shows up inline. That said, screenshots of code are not that helpful (just paste the code, properly formatted, instead). And this screenshot doesn't highlight the line that fails or anything. The exact error message text is useful.

Comment: You should check the VB6 project references for the becubed DLL or whatever file(s) that are expected.